# List View - search list with filter using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I'm having problems with the filter result, here is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="populerNameKey">
```

The list item:

```
<ul id="destPopuler">
  <li class="country">England</li>
  <li class="testing"><a href="#">Liverpool</a></li>
  <li class="testing"><a href="#">London</a></li>
  <li class="country">Italy</li>
  <li class="testing"><a href="#">Roma</a></li>
  <li class="testing"><a href="#">Milan</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the complete JavaScript here:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/zvo6hw4c/5/)

The problem is when I type "Spain" letter by letter, the result is lost. I want that it still exists. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: what is the bug ? what is happening what is expected?

Comment: if i typing "liverpool" letter by letter, the result is lost. I want it still exist @guradio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code get problem when you type liverpol with lower case first and your text value is have a proper value, with Upper case first.
You should same your input value and search value text fist.

You can do that with

.toLowerCase function

.toUpperCase funtion

here some link for reference [toLowerCase toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

```
$("#populerNameKey").on('keyup', function(){
var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
$("#destPopuler li").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().search(value) > -1) {
        $(this).show();
        $(this).prev('.country').last().show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});   
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and reference. I have another mistake again, if I type 'spain', why the previous header list remains called? https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/zvo6hw4c/5/

Comment: try to change .prevAll() to .prev() and .first() to .last  previous header still remains because you use prevAll() and first()

Answer (score 2):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a.header {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  cursor: default;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#" class="header">C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

try this one.

Comment: thank you, looks like in w3schools. this one of my reference

Comment: If you Satisfied this answer Vote me check left side box

Comment: What are your recommendations for excluding the header classed list items from the search in cases where "A" is changed to "Title", for example, and how is it possible to make header list items visible for each result throughout the search process - beginning to end? I think it would be more accessible if header was excluded from the search, and that it remained visible throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Use .toLowerCase() on both the input and the value of the list item

You're comparing upper-case letters with lower-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a case insensitive search. You could use a regular expression ([RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)) with an ignore case (`i`) flag. Like `RegExp(value, "i")`. This will ignore the case while doing a comparison. So, you've to change

```
$(this).text().search(value) > -1
```

to

```
$(this).text().search(RegExp(value, "i")) > -1
```